# Unable to upgrade from Python 3.7.9 to Python 3.10

Tags: python, windows

I installed a while ago the Python version 3.9 - and more recently the 3.10 - only to realize that my computer continued to use Python 3.7.9 all this time.

The problem is that I'm trying to install some packages that are not compatible with 3.7.9 anymore, but I'm not able to update the version that Windows is using.

I tried moving the 3.10 version to the top of my PATH environment variables. I tried removing the 3.7 version completely from PATH. Nothing works. I am still getting 3.7.9 with the "python --version" command.

Interestingly, this is what I get with the "where python" command:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
```

Any idea how to resolve this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: i think you tried installing python through the microsoft store, instead of the python official site, so you have to uninstall it from there, i'd recommend removing all versions of python through both the microsoft store and the control panel then installing a fresh install of python from the official site.

Comment: Indeed I had a version from the miscrosoft store. I uninstalled it and reinstalled python from the official site. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall *all* installed versions of python, including those from the "microsoft store".

Then install the Python 3.10 version from `python.org`.

In the setup window, select "Install launcher for all users" if you have administrator access on your PC. Then click "Install now" and let the installer do its thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's the correct solution. The issue was that I had a version from the "microsoft store"